# What is rich_editing?

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, user-meta

I wanted to learn more about shortcodes with button implementation since I do not use them much and I have been doing a lot of research on the topic and the questions and tutorials I run across use a conditional with `get_user_option( 'rich_editing' ) == 'true'`.  I tried a [search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=rich_editing) on the site but browsing through I didn't see anyone dive into the specifics and when I searched the codex it lands me on [`get_userdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) with:

[image]

So what is `rich_editing` actually doing if you are already using `if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && ! current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `rich_editing` user option stores this check box value:

[image: rich editing]

wether or not do enable the visual editor for that particular user.

If it's disabled then the content editor will look like this:

[image: no visual editor here]

Comment: It is actually unbelievable that after years of "decisions, not options" this one still exists.

Comment: yes I agree, I think this option wouldn't have a change if we would have proposed it today ;-) @MarkKaplun

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34681, started a ticket to remove it

Comment: I like your initiative ;-)  I think I've never used this option and I don't know anyone that have used it  @MarkKaplun

Comment: funny, there was another similar ticket posted just few minutes later ;-) @MarkKaplun

Comment: Would be a bad idea to remove it, see: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/325234/184905

Comment: This option is still available in WordPress admin UI 5.4 and seems to be adjusted to Gutenberg. One can also filter it, like shown in the linked answer about a bugged hosting environment.